Instantaneous correlation and terminal correlation - 6.29
I am trying to derive the $(6.29)$ equation from brigo and Mercurio book.
We have

$dF_2(t)= \sigma_{2,\beta(t)}F_2(t)dW_2(t)$

$dF_3(t)=   
   \frac{\delta_3\sigma_{3,\beta(t)}^2F_3^2(t)}{1+\delta_3F_3(t)}dt +   
   \sigma_{3,\beta(t)}F3(t)dW_3(t)$


We are looking to calculate $E^2[(F_2(T1)-F_2(0))(ln[F_3(T1)] -ln[F_3(0)])]$
$F_2(T1)-F_2(0)=\sigma_{2,\beta(t)}F_2(0)dW_2(t)$
$ln[F_3(T1)] -ln[F_3(0)]= (\frac{\delta_3\sigma_{3,\beta(t)}^2F_3(t)}{1+\delta_3F_3(t)} - \frac{\sigma_{3,\beta(t)}^2}{2})dt + \sigma_{3,\beta(t)}dW_3(t)$
$(F_2(T1)−F_2(0))(ln[F_3(T1)]−ln[F_3(0)])=F_2(0)\sigma_{2,\beta(t)}\sigma_{3,\beta(t)}dW_3(t)dW_2(t)$
$dW_3(t)dW_2(t)=\rho_{3,2} dt$ =>$F_2(0)\rho_{3,2}\sigma_{2,\beta(t)}\sigma_{3,\beta(t)} dt$
Is this correct?
Regards
